# Error in GiftedChat, Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-gifted-chat

I want to use `react-native-gifted-chat` and then when I try to call it, it keeps getting this error:

> ```
> Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either
> doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on
> every render.
>     in GiftedChat (created by Chat)
>     in Chat (created by SceneView)
>     in StaticContainer
>     in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
>     in SceneView (created by CardContainer)
>     in RCTView (created by View)
>     in View (created by CardContainer)
>     in RCTView (created by View)
>     in View (created by CardContainer)
>     in RCTView (created by View)
>     in View
>     in CardSheet (created by Card)
>     in RCTView (created by View)
>     ...
> ```

```
import React from "react";
import { GiftedChat } from 'react-native-gifted-chat';

export default function Chat() {
  return (
    <View>
      <GiftedChat />
    </View>
  )
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: read the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gifted-chat) properly and add all the necessary props for it to work propperly

Comment: Thanks bro, it actually need to define onSend() in GiftedChat